Why does passing a string to a tuple in Rust cause ownership to shift?
Here is a simple Rust code, can be compiled and passed:
fn return_two_value(str:String) -> (String , usize){
    let len = str.len();
    (str,len)
}

But trying to simplify one step won't do. Like this:
fn return_two_value(str:String) -> (String , usize){
    (str,str.len())
}

I asked AI and it told me (str,str.len()) is feasible.  Is it a problem with my Rust version?
The code can be modified in this way:
fn return_two_value_(str:String) -> (usize,String){
    (str.len(),str)
}


"I asked AI and it told me (str,str.len()) is feasible, Is it a problem with my Rust version?" ­– no, AI just can't code it spits out what happens to look like code, not actual code, sometimes it happenes to be close enough to compile.


Why does passing a string to a tuple in Rust cause ownership to shift?

Because that's the entire thing of Rust?
Rust has an affine type system, so every "object" has one owner, and objects are moved when used[1]. You're putting the string in a tuple, so rust moves the string into the tuple, and the old name / location becomes invalid.
Your code works when flipped because Rust intentionally tries to keep code execution left-to-right for consistency and simplicity (as it already has a pretty high complexity load). So when creating a tuple, it evaluates the first item, then the second, then the third, ..., same when evaluating parameters to call a function.
That's not always convenient but the consistency is helpful compared to evaluating in an arbitrary order which might "just work" in more situations, but then would be hopelessly entangled and very difficult to understand when side effects are involved.

[1]: borrowing does not count as a use, and the Copy trait lets you opt into something closer to normal types, but the type system's logic doesn't fundamentally change which is why Copy is subject to a large host of restrictions
